# how can i check devices are support vuforia mid air?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

When i check by condition some devices return true but in actual they are not supported...

how i can check devices are mid air supported or not ?

any have updated devices list ?

like

"samsung SM-N920V",
            "samsung SM-N920S",
            "samsung SM-N9208",
            "samsung SM-N920K",
            "samsung SM-N920L",
            "samsung SM-N920C",
            "samsung SM-N920I",
            "samsung SM-N9200",
            "samsung SM-N920T",
            "samsung SM-N920P",
            "samsung SM-N920G",
            "samsung SAMSUNG-SM-N920A",
            "samsung SM-N920W8",
            "samsung SM-G920F",
            "samsung SM-G920S",
            "samsung SM-G920I",
            "samsung SM-G920K",
            "samsung SM-G920L",
            "samsung SM-G9200",
            "samsung SM-G920P",
            "samsung SM-G920V",
            "samsung SM-G9209",
            "samsung SM-G920W8",
            "samsung SM-G9208",
            "samsung SAMSUNG-SM-G920A",
            "samsung SM-G920T",
            "samsung SM-G920R4",
            "samsung SM-G920R7",
            "samsung SM-G920X",
            "samsung SM-G925I",
            "samsung SM-G925S",
            "samsung SM-G9250",
            "samsung SM-G925K",
            "samsung SM-G925F",
            "samsung SM-G925L",
            "samsung SM-G925V",
            "samsung SM-G925W8",
            "samsung SM-G925T",
            "samsung SM-G925P",
            "samsung SAMSUNG-SM-G925A",
            "samsung SM-G925X",
            "samsung SM-G930F",
            "samsung SM-G930K",
            "samsung SM-G930L",
            "samsung SM-G930S",
            "samsung SM-G930W8",
            "samsung SAMSUNG-SM-G930A",
            "samsung SM-G930P",
            "samsung SM-G930V",
            "samsung SM-G9300",
            "samsung SM-G930T",
            "samsung SM-G930R4",
            "samsung SM-G9308",
            "samsung SM-G930U",
            "samsung SM-G930T1",
            "samsung SAMSUNG-SM-G930AZ",
            "samsung SM-G930VL",
            "samsung SM-G930R7",
            "samsung SM-G930R6",
            "samsung SM-G935F",
            "samsung SM-G935S",
            "samsung SM-G935K",
            "samsung SM-G935X",
            "samsung SM-G935L",
            "samsung SM-G935W8",
            "samsung SM-G935U",
            "samsung SM-G935V",
            "samsung SM-G935T",
            "samsung SM-G935P",
            "samsung SM-G9350",
            "samsung SAMSUNG-SM-G935A",
            "samsung SM-G935R4",
            "samsung SM-N950F",
            "samsung SM-N950XN",
            "samsung SM-N950N",
            "samsung SM-N950U",
            "samsung SM-N9500",
            "samsung SM-G950F",
            "samsung SM-G950N",
            "samsung SM-G950X",
            "samsung SM-G950XN",
            "samsung SM-G950U",
            "samsung SM-G9500",
            "samsung SM-G950U1",
            "samsung SM-G950W",
            "samsung SM-G9508",
            "samsung SM-G950K",
            "samsung SM-G950XC",
            "samsung SM-G955F",
            "samsung SM-G955N",
            "samsung SM-G955X",
            "samsung SM-G955XN",
            "samsung SM-G955U",
            "samsung SM-G9550",
            "samsung SM-G955U1",
            "samsung SM-G955W",
            "samsung SM-G955XC",
            "Xiaomi Redmi 3S",
            "OPPO OPPO R9sk",
            "OPPO OPPO R9st",
            "OPPO OPPO R9s",
            "OPPO OPPO R9s Plus",
            "OPPO OPPO R11",
            "OPPO OPPO R11t",
            "Google Pixel",
            "Google Pixel 2",
            "Google Pixel 2 XL",
            "Huawei Nexus 6P",
            "motorola Moto G (4)",
            "iPad 6,11",
            "iPad 6,12",
            "iPad4,1",
            "iPad4,2",
            "iPad4,3",
            "iPad5,3",
            "iPad5,4",
            "iPad4,4",
            "iPad4,5",
            "iPad4,6",
            "iPad4,7",
            "iPad4,8",
            "iPad4,9",
            "iPad5,1",
            "iPad5,2",
            "iPhone6,1",
            "iPhone6,2",
            "iPhone8,4",
            "iPhone7,2",
            "iPhone7,1",
            "iPhone8,1",
            "iPhone8,2",
            "iPhone9,1",
            "iPhone9,3",
            "iPhone9,2",
            "iPhone9,4",
            "iPhone10,1",
            "iPhone10,4",
            "iPhone10,2",
            "iPhone10,5",
            "iPhone10,3",
            "iPhone10,6",
            "iPad6,7",
            "iPad6,8",
            "iPad7,3",
            "iPad7,4",
            "iPad7,1",
            "iPad7,2",
            "iPad6,3",
            "iPad6,4"

Comment: How is this a coding related question? How would you define "mid air" for something that is purely based on image recognition?

Comment: this code add in  script and check running devices are available in this list ?

Comment: but i need proper condition which are perfect return a value device support a mid air ? otherwise i want updated devices list.